# ResultSet: Get RowId (index in jdbc) from the inserted row

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, rowid

Lets see the list of commands for the abstract database (JDBC)

```
 rs.moveToInsertRow(); 
 rs.updateString(1, "AINSWORTH"); 
 rs.updateInt(2,35);
 rs.updateBoolean(3, true);
 rs.insertRow();
```

Ok, after that I expected that

```
rs.getRow(); //Retrieves the current row number.
```

returns new row id for this row, but I got null.

Read documnetation:

> After inserting the row the ResultSet still pointing to the insert row. However, you cannot be certain what will happen if you try to access it, once the row has been inserted. Therefore you should move the ResultSet to a valid position after inserting the new row.

Ok, call

```
rs.moveToCurrentRow();
```

And question. How to move forward to inserted row and get rowId (jdbc index, not sql)? I tried

```
rs.previous();
```

but got exception. rs.last() move to last row (not inserted)

Please, do not propose to calculate and read specal columns (rowid for ORACLE). 
I don't find the similar question on stackoverflow, but found with the similar title.
My environment is java 6 and oracle 11 with odbc14.jar

Comment: You are misinterpreting the meaning of `getRow()`: it is the **index** in the result set. It has nothing to do with a generated key or row_id.

Comment: Ok, I need index, not id of row.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to clarify that: rowid has a specific meaning (both in SQL and JDBC).

Comment: You might want to check what [`DatabaseMetaData.wnInsertsAreVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#ownInsertsAreVisible-int-) for your current result set type. If it is false, then the result set won't contain the inserted row, so there is no index to obtain.

Comment: getMetaData().ownInsertsAreVisible( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE) is false. Can I change this?

Comment: You might want to check if `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` returns true and use that instead, but otherwise there is probably no way to do this.

Comment: Of cource I checked. ownInsertsAreVisible( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE) is also false

Comment: Then I am afraid it is simply not possible with this driver.

Comment: Can you suggert me another driver for oracle?

Comment: I am not aware of other drivers other than those provided by Oracle.